# How to Fetch Number from This Array Dynamically?

Tags: php, html

Am working on my personal project.. But I have stuck here since yesterday without sucess.. Can Anyone help me please? And thanks in advance.

I have Variable $IDs which is list of TMDBIDs.. That Variable is array I have converted to number list using foreach loop so I can use as Variable $tmdbid, this one worked with no problem..

But The issue start here when I want to get Only Season_number of each data produced from tmdbapi array. How to do that.. Can Anyone help me Please?

Here is my code

**NOTE: This is an Edit I have included all the code as requested by @RiggsFolly**

```
<?php

$tmdbapi = "25ae6e919xxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

// Converting JSON to array
$movieslist = file_get_contents('https://example.com/dump/tv');
$tmdbdata = json_decode($movieslist, true);

//Filtering only TMDB ID

$IDs = array();
foreach($tmdbdata as $key => $val) {
    array_push($IDs, $tmdbdata[$key]);
}

$count = -1;

/*---------------------- The number of records to display per page -----------*/
$page_size = 10;

// Calculate total number of records, and total number of pages
$total_records = count($IDs);
$total_pages   = ceil($total_records / $page_size);

// Validation: Page to display can not be greater than the total number of pages
if ($page > $total_pages) {
    $page = $total_pages;
}

// Validation: Page to display can not be less than 1
if ($page < 1) {
    $page = 1;
}

// Calculate the position of the first record of the page to display
$offset = ($page - 1) * $page_size;

// Get the subset of records to be displayed from the array
$IDs = array_slice($IDs, $offset, $page_size);

// variables for pagination links
$page_first = $page > 1 ? 1 : '';
$page_prev  = $page > 1 ? $page-1 : '';
$page_next  = $page < $total_pages ? $page + 1 : '';
$page_last  = $page < $total_pages ? $total_pages : '';

/*--------------------------- Getting Seasons numbers from TMDBID ------------*/

$tvdata = array();
foreach ($IDs as $tmdbid1):
    $tvdata[] = file_get_contents('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/tv/'.$tmdbid1.'?api_key='.$tmdbapi.'&language=en-US');

    // Converting JSON to array
    $seasons = array();
endforeach;
$length = count($tvdata);
for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
    $seasons[] = json_decode($tvdata[$i], true);
}

//Filtering only seasons_number

$seasons_numbers = array();
foreach ($seasons as $seasons_list) {
    $seasons_numbers[] = $seasons_list['seasons'][0]['season_number']; 
}

echo 'Printing Seasons';

print "<pre>";
print_r($seasons_numbers);
print "</pre>";

?>
```

Now I want to Get list of every Season_Number from of each TMDBID dynamically from Array $seasons

Here is the Results from Array $seasons

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [adult] => 
            [backdrop_path] => /6ayRwd2P0K3d1TDaePcxvDkDjsv.jpg
            [created_by] => Array()

            [episode_run_time] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 65
                )

            [first_air_date] => 2019-11-22
            [genres] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 18
                            [name] => Drama
                        )

                )

            [homepage] => https://www.netflix.com/title/80244846
            [id] => 86456
            [in_production] => 
            [languages] => Array
                (
                    [0] => en
                )

            [last_air_date] => 2019-11-22
            [last_episode_to_air] => Array
                (
                    [air_date] => 2019-11-22
                    [episode_number] => 8
                    [id] => 1991644
                    [name] => These Old Bones
                    [overview] => A mysterious mountain woman steps into the spotlight as a lawyer struggles to find her voice in this story of seeing, believing and everything between.
                    [production_code] => 
                    [runtime] => 86
                    [season_number] => 1
                    [show_id] => 86456
                    [still_path] => /rpiimwUs6buZozBPF3kv08NohUX.jpg
                    [vote_average] => 5
                    [vote_count] => 3
                )

            [name] => Dolly Parton's Heartstrings
            [next_episode_to_air] => 
            [networks] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 213
                            [name] => Netflix
                            [logo_path] => /wwemzKWzjKYJFfCeiB57q3r4Bcm.png
                            [origin_country] => 
                        )

                )

            [number_of_episodes] => 8
            [number_of_seasons] => 1
            [origin_country] => Array
                (
                    [0] => US
                )

            [original_language] => en
            [original_name] => Dolly Parton's Heartstrings
            [overview] => Eight stories celebrating family, faith, love and forgiveness come to life in this series inspired by Dolly Parton's iconic country music catalog.
            [popularity] => 5.595
            [poster_path] => /jW41XQ28sRYf7WDTtPuQaymlOxW.jpg
            [production_companies] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1957
                            [logo_path] => /3T19XSr6yqaLNK8uJWFImPgRax0.png
                            [name] => Warner Bros. Television
                            [origin_country] => US
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 5842
                            [logo_path] => 
                            [name] => Sandollar Productions
                            [origin_country] => US
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 114326
                            [logo_path] => 
                            [name] => Magnolia Hill Productions
                            [origin_country] => US
                        )

                )

            [production_countries] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [iso_3166_1] => US
                            [name] => United States of America
                        )

                )

            [seasons] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [air_date] => 2019-11-22
                            [episode_count] => 8
                            [id] => 118100
                            [name] => Season 1
                            [overview] => 
                            [poster_path] => /jW41XQ28sRYf7WDTtPuQaymlOxW.jpg
                            [season_number] => 1
                        )

                )

            [spoken_languages] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [english_name] => English
                            [iso_639_1] => en
                            [name] => English
                        )

                )

            [status] => Ended
            [tagline] => 8 Dolly songs. 8 Dolly stories.
            [type] => Miniseries
            [vote_average] => 7.2
            [vote_count] => 18
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [adult] => 
            [backdrop_path] => 
            [created_by] => Array
                (
                )

            [episode_run_time] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 25
                )

            [first_air_date] => 1994-10-06
            [genres] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 10751
                            [name] => Family
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 35
                            [name] => Comedy
                        )

                )

            [homepage] => 
            [id] => 20507
            [in_production] => 
            [languages] => Array
                (
                )

            [last_air_date] => 1997-08-26
            [last_episode_to_air] => Array
                (
                    [air_date] => 1997-08-26
                    [episode_number] => 12
                    [id] => 586113
                    [name] => Season 3, Episode 12
                    [overview] => 
                    [production_code] => 
                    [runtime] => 25
                    [season_number] => 3
                    [show_id] => 20507
                    [still_path] => 
                    [vote_average] => 0
                    [vote_count] => 0
                )

            [name] => Pirates
            [next_episode_to_air] => 
            [networks] => Array
                (
                )

            [number_of_episodes] => 18
            [number_of_seasons] => 3
            [origin_country] => Array
                (
                    [0] => GB
                )

            [original_language] => en
            [original_name] => Pirates
            [overview] => Pirates is a British children's television sitcom about a family of pirates living in a council house. It featured a number of bizarre characters, such as the "Man in a Sack" and a baby in a pram which was never seen, but gave off a mysterious green glow. The series ran from 1994 to 1997 on Children's BBC, and featured Liz Smith as "Gran".
            [popularity] => 0.856
            [poster_path] => 
            [production_companies] => Array ()
            [production_countries] => Array ()

            [seasons] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [air_date] => 1994-10-06
                            [episode_count] => 5
                            [id] => 30535
                            [name] => Season 1
                            [overview] => 
                            [poster_path] => 
                            [season_number] => 1
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [air_date] => 1995-10-04
                            [episode_count] => 5
                            [id] => 30536
                            [name] => Season 2
                            [overview] => 
                            [poster_path] => 
                            [season_number] => 2
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [air_date] => 1997-03-18
                            [episode_count] => 8
                            [id] => 30537
                            [name] => Season 3
                            [overview] => 
                            [poster_path] => 
                            [season_number] => 3
                        )

                )

            [spoken_languages] => Array
                (
                )

            [status] => Ended
            [tagline] => 
            [type] => Scripted
            [vote_average] => 0
            [vote_count] => 0
        )

And more Arrays.....
```

I want to get data of every [seasons] [season_number]

How can I Do it?

I have Tried

```
$seasons_numbers = array();
foreach ($seasons as $seasons_list) {
    $seasons_numbers[] = $seasons_list['seasons'][0]['season_number']; 
}
```

The result

```
Array
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 1
    [3] => 1
    [4] => 1
    [5] => 1
    [6] => 
    [7] => 1
    [8] => 1
    [9] => 1
)
```

It means it only take The ID from the first seasons only.. and it not dynamic

Then I have tried

```
$seasons_numbers = array();
foreach ($seasons as $seasons_list) {
    $seasons_numbers[] = $seasons[$i -1]['seasons'][0]['season_number']; 
}
```

And getting the same results..

How can I make it Index of Seasons Array more dynamic instead of putting [0] it should be something dynamic ['seasons'][0]['season_number'];

How to make it dynamic and list all seasons and not only the first season, for example if the tvshow have 3  seasons it should list all 3 seasons from the tvshow

Thanks.

Comment: I think you need to show how these fragment actually work together. I mean show us the real code as a block, dont pick out little bits

Comment: I have defined it in the code above.. The first code I added on this Post.. But here it is

$length = count($tvdata);
for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
    $seasons[] = json_decode($tvdata[$i], true);
}

Comment: Code goes in the Question please, where we can read it

Comment: THis `foreach ($seasons as $seasons_list) {  $seasons_numbers[] = $seasons[0]['seasons'][0]['season_number']; }` is looping over something, but inside the loop you make no use of the loop. The `$seasons_numbers[] = $seasons[0]['seasons'][0]['season_number'];` never uses any part of the loop

Comment: @RiggsFolly I have edited the code Please see full code.. Above

Comment: Thanks @RiggsFolly For Pointing Out.. I wonder why I ddn't see it lol.. The result now is..

Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 1
    [3] => 1
    [4] => 1
    [5] => 1
    [6] => 
    [7] => 1
    [8] => 1
    [9] => 1
)

Comment: Also dont see where `$page` gets defined

Comment: With page I get it with GET ISSET.. that is not problem.. here it is

$page = (isset($_GET['page'])) && is_numeric($_GET['page']) ? intval($_GET['page']) : '0';
$auto = (isset($_GET['auto'])) && is_numeric($_GET['auto']) ? intval($_GET['auto']) : '0';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little study of the shape of the data returned and I get here

```
$page = 1;  // set for testing

$tmdbapi = "25ae6e919c5b9ee9058e04b9987bd921";

// Converting JSON to array
$movieslist = file_get_contents('https://listmovies.9animetv.live/dump/tv');
$tmdbdata = json_decode($movieslist, true);

//Filtering only TMDB ID

$IDs = array_values($tmdbdata);

$count = -1;

/*---------------------- The number of records to display per page -----------*/
$page_size = 10;

// Calculate total number of records, and total number of pages
$total_records = count($IDs);
$total_pages   = ceil($total_records / $page_size);

// Validation: Page to display can not be greater than the total number of pages
if ($page > $total_pages) {
    $page = $total_pages;
}

// Validation: Page to display can not be less than 1
if ($page < 1) {
    $page = 1;
}

// Calculate the position of the first record of the page to display
$offset = ($page - 1) * $page_size;

// Get the subset of records to be displayed from the array
$IDs = array_slice($IDs, $offset, $page_size);

// variables for pagination links
$page_first = $page > 1 ? 1 : '';
$page_prev  = $page > 1 ? $page-1 : '';
$page_next  = $page < $total_pages ? $page + 1 : '';
$page_last  = $page < $total_pages ? $total_pages : '';

/*--------------------------- Getting Seasons numbers from TMDBID ------------*/

$tvdata = array();
foreach ($IDs as $id):
    if ( $id != 0 ) :
        $tvdata[] = file_get_contents('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/tv/'.$id.'?api_key='.$tmdbapi.'&language=en-US');
    endif;
endforeach;

// Converting JSON to array
$seasons = [];
$length = count($tvdata);
foreach ($tvdata as $tvd) {
    $seasons[] = json_decode($tvd);     // use the object :)
}

//Filtering only seasons_number

$seasons_numbers = [];
foreach ($seasons as $aSeason) {
    foreach ( $aSeason->seasons as $season) {
        $seasons_numbers[] = $season->season_number; 
    }
}

echo 'Printing Seasons';

print "<pre>";
print_r($seasons_numbers);
print "</pre>";

?>
```

RESULT

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 1
    [3] => 1
    [4] => 1
    [5] => 1
    [6] => 2
    [7] => 3
    [8] => 1
    [9] => 2
    [10] => 3
    [11] => 1
    [12] => 1
```